# Nodejs/Express/Cookies: how do you set signed cookies with a secret

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, setcookie

In my directory i have app.js And Index.htmml ; I am trying to set cookies from App.js; I have tried:-

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  http = require('http'),
  cookieparser = require ('cookie-parser'),
  httpServer = http.Server(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/data'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

 let options = {
        maxAge: 60000, // would expire after 1 minutes
        httpOnly: true, 
        signed: true ,
        secret: 'secret'
    }

    // Set cookie

  app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));

  res.cookie('cookieName', 'Success', options)

 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

});

app.listen(8080);
```

When i run app.js from Cmd It dissappoints me with this error
Thanks in advance for help

```
Error: cookieParser("secret") required for signed cookies
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a secret key which will be used while signing the cookie.

You can do this by adding the following line to your code.

```
app.use(cookieparser("secret"));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the snippet, you are using the `express-session` module like so:

```js
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 'keyboard cat', ... }));
```

That is already saying that you want cookies to be signed. Therefore, in your cookie `options` you can remove the option `signed: true` since it will be redundant.

And on a last note, you need to improve that code.